# Getting properties from multiple objects if it exists

Tags: javascript, object

I have an object like this for example:

```
var obj = {
    107: {name: "test", id: 772},
    124: {name: "hello", id: 123},
    120: {id: 213}
}
```

How can I retrieve an array of `name`s from `obj`, for example the output should be: `["test", "hello"]`

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Will your object always be in this form, or will it be arbitrarily deep — might 'name' be nested further down?

Comment: @Mark_M It will always be in this form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the functions `reduce`, `Object.values` and the function `includes` to avoid repeated values.

```js
var obj = {
    '107': {name: "test", id: 772},
    '124': {name: "hello", id: 123},
    '125': {name: "hello", id: 1233},
    '120': {id: 213}
}

var result = Object.values(obj).reduce((a, {name}) => {
  if (name && !a.includes(name)) a.push(name);
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

To avoid repeated values, you can use the Object `Set` as well:

```js
var obj = {
    '107': {name: "test", id: 772},
    '124': {name: "hello", id: 123},
    '125': {name: "hello", id: 1233},
    '120': {id: 213}
}

var result = Array.from(Object.values(obj).reduce((a, {name}) => {
  if (name) a.add(name);
  return a;
}, new Set()).values());

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks, also another quick follow up question, how would I go about only retrieving 1 of each `name`? For example if there was 3 "hello"s only 1 would be appended to the array

Answer (score 2):

Since the object is always in this form you can do a one-line filter/map:

```js
var obj = { 107: {name: "test", id: 772},124: {name: "hello", id: 123},120: {id: 213}}

var names = Object.values(obj).filter(v => v.name).map(i => i.name)

console.log(names)
```

Comment: Two unnecessary loops

Comment: @Ele I suppose it depends on how much you value succinct, functional code versus how much real-world time you're talking about. I would be curious to see a benchmark if you have one.

Comment: Filter and then map is a waste of time.

Comment: @Ele how much time?

Comment: The sample of the OP is very tiny.  However, we the community always has to think beyond that.  Imagine a big array with your approach looping twice.  That's not ok.

Comment: @Ele, without a benchmark or a real-world situation, it's all academic and a case of premature optimization.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Object.keys()` to get an array of keys for the obj object, then reduce though those:

```js
const obj = {
  107: {name: "test", id: 772},
  124: {name: "hello", id: 123},
  120: {id: 213}
}

console.log(
  Object.keys(obj).reduce((a,key) => {
    obj[key].name && a.push(obj[key].name)
    return a
  },[])  
)
```

Comment: Thanks, also another quick follow up question, how would I go about only retrieving 1 of each `name`? For example if there was 3 "hello"s only 1 would be appended to the array

Comment: Here, since `a` (the accumulator) for the reduce function already contains any previous names, you can simply change the inside of the reduce function to check if that value already exists in the accumulator:
`if (obj[key].name && a.indexOf(obj[key].name) === -1) {
      a.push(obj[key].name
      return a
    }
`